# Laravel can I add two update method on a resource controller

Tags: laravel, php-7, laravel-5.7, laravel-controller

I'm new to laravel and I would like to add another Update method from the created resource controller UsersController.
something like this:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    "logic here"
}
  public function update2(Request $request, $id)
{
    "logic here"
}
```

but i do not know how to access "update2". is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only need add another route to your `routes/web.php` file. For example:

```
Route::post('/users/{user}/update2', 'UsersController@update2');
```

As you've mentioned it being a resource controller, you may have already added something similar to:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

This will create the corresponding `index`, `show`, `store`, `update`, and `destroy` routes.

Comment: how do I call the update in resource controller  `action="{{ route('FleetAdmin.update_user', $user->id) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access update2 like this :

```
Route::get('route-name', 'YourCOntroller@update2');
```

Answer (score -1):

Resource route will create URL like `user/{id}`

You have to create another route for the update2 in web.php like

Route::put('user/{id}/update2', 'V1\UserController@update2');